# gflags arguments extraction doesn't work on debug mode (C++)

Tags: c++, gflags

I'm using gflags to parse command line parameters of a c++ application (v140, x64).
For some reason, I get different results on Release and Debug mode. 
In debug mode, the argument is not identified.

**code**

```
#include <gflags/gflags.h>
DEFINE_string(str_arg, "default param value", "string value");

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "str value before glog init: " + FLAGS_str_arg << std::endl;
    //third parameter is set to false. setting it to true doesn't solve the problem
    google::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, false);
    std::cout << "str value after glog init: " + FLAGS_str_arg << std::endl;
}
```

**execution command**

```
app.exe -str_arg new_val
```

**output in Release mode**

```
str value before glog init: default param value
str value after glog init: new_val
```

**output in Debug mode**

```
str value before glog init: default param value
str value after glog init: default param value
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that you forgot to set the arguments when you use the debugger.  It is an extra step, Project > Properties > Debugging, "Command Arguments" setting.  Also make sure that the Configuration and Platform comboboxes at the top of the dialog are set correctly, that goes wrong too often.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but I work through command line, so that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that in debug mode strings are not showing up. To solve this problem i had to compile gflags release and **debug** libraries.
In the *install/bin* directory there are now:

- gflags.dll
- gflags_debug.dll